# Quarkus Getting Started project failed to produce native image

Tags: quarkus

I followed the instructions on https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image-guide but it failes with the error message "Failed to generate a native image"

I work on MacOS, having installed Maven 3.6.0.
The result of the command

```
mvn package -Pnative
```

ends up with the following error message:

```
Error: Error compiling query code (in /var/folders/cm/t91m64zj34d757jrhx6r3lz9kl946h/T/SVM-4468965107592954019/LibFFIHeaderDirectives.c). Compiler command  gcc -I/Applications/graalvm-ce-1.0.0-rc14/Contents/Home/jre/lib/svm/clibraries/darwin-amd64/include /var/folders/cm/t91m64zj34d757jrhx6r3lz9kl946h/T/SVM-4468965107592954019/LibFFIHeaderDirectives.c -o /var/folders/cm/t91m64zj34d757jrhx6r3lz9kl946h/T/SVM-4468965107592954019/LibFFIHeaderDirectives output included error: xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
Error: Image building with exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.764 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-04T16:39:27+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.12.0:native-image (default) on project getting-started: Failed to generate a native image: Failed to build native image: Image generation failed -> [Help 1]
```

Any ideas  what's the issue ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have GraalVM properly installed?

Comment: I am sure:     
`lli --version
Graal LLVM 6.0.0 (GraalVM CE Native 1.0.0-rc14)`

Comment: Not sure what is going on (since I don't use Mac), but the installation seems botched...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you installed the XCode CLI tools? This command will install them:

```
xcode-select --install
```